# Do I need an online subscription to play Fortnite on Xbox or PS4?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

Can someone tell me if I need to purchase the online subscription in order to download and play Fortnite on Xbox? It's for my children. I will purchase either the XBOX or PS4. Also am I capable of putting this on a laptop or Chromebook?

Answer (score 4):

You need an Xbox Live Gold subscription while not needing a Playstation Plus or Nintendo Switch Online subscription.

The source is right here: [Epic Games FAQ](https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/en-US/faq)
(The answers on are the 2,3,4  Q/A)

To answer your other question, you can play Fortnite: Battle Royale (And Save the World) on a laptop, or any other PC but you need to make sure it is compatible with so.

Answer (score -2):

There is no need for xbox live and I would assume the same for whatever playstations online sub is. I've been playing fortnite on xbox and nintendo switch without need for either of their online sub services.

Comment: [Epic games once said on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/FortNiteBR/comments/71b8g2/fortnite_battle_royale_free_sept_26_faq/dn9mbdf/) that you do in fact need an xbox live account to play. Has that changed since release?

Answer (score -4):

Fortnite is free-to-play, so you do not need to purchase anything, however, there is the option to purchase in-game cosmetics that have no effect on your stats. You can also purchase Save the World, a player versus environment feature.

Comment: I think you should elaborate that while fortnite is free, the OP will need to have a subscription to XBOX live to do online play. I dont know a lot about PS4 online play, but I dont think it costs extra.. could be wrong though.